# Correct preposition or word: "I want to evaluate your opinion and comprehension of/about ..."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct way of saying the following?

*I want to evaluate your opinion and comprehension of/about this image?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to use *of* here.

*About* would pair nicely with *opinion* if it were on its own in the sentence; however, *of* pairs just as well with it, and must go with *comprehension*.

Comment: Is "You'd want to use ..." more colloquial than "You should use ..."?

Comment: I would say so, yes.  I feel that if I'd said that OP *should* use this or that that I am some sort of authority on the matter rather than an enthusiast.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the two concepts - comprehension and opinion, are too different to be combined together in the same expression.  To me, comprehension is objective and opinion is subjective. 
Are you interested in the kind of comprehension that is quantifiable, e.g. is the person able to find 10 differences or find hidden objects in the image? Or are you soliciting their subjective opinion on art?

If the latter, I would rephrase the question to something like this:
I would like to know how you interpret this image and your opinion of it.

Comment: Yes, truly I am interested in objective comprehension and subjective opinion. @Raissa I am not an expert but the structure of  sentence you have proposed seems to be not  consistent to me as far as two ideas are concerned